# Columns wont align Horizontally in Bootstrap 5

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Im trying to make a Shopping Cart using php and Bootstrap 5. I specified the classes but the items still stacks vertically. I want it to be beside each other and align Horizontally

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>shopping cart</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="cart.css">
</head>
<body>
        <div class="container">

        <?php

        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','1234','cart');
        $query = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER by id ASC';
        $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

        if ($result) {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                    ?>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                        <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
                            <div class="products">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>">
                                <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></h4>
                                <h4>$ <?php echo $product['price'];  ?></h4>
                                <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"/>
                                <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $product['price']; ?>"/>
                                <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-info" value="Add to Cart"/>
                            
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    </div>
           
                    <?php 
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
    </div>


    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

is there something that im missing?? I tried evrything that i know of T^T

ps. Im still a novice when it comes to Web Developing so please have mercy on me T^T ;3

Answer (score 0):

You have a "row" around each "column", that means each row has only one column. Try to put the "row" outside the loop so multiple columns fall within it. You can have as many columns in a row as you like. Something like this:

```
<?php

    if ($result) {
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php
            while($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                    <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
                        <div class="products">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>">
                            <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></h4>
                            <h4>$ <?php echo $product['price'];  ?></h4>
                            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $product['price']; ?>"/>
                            <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-info" value="Add to Cart"/>
                        
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php 
            }
            ?>
            </div>
            <?php
         }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I did it but the cards still didnt align horizontally, instead, it just disarranged my cards

Comment: @SqueezyAbby: We cannot see what you see and we cannot run your code. "disarranged" is just too vague to know what's really going on. Why not ask a new question, specifically about this "disarranged" layout. You will get much better answers when the code example, in your question, does not rely on database access. After all, this access is not essential for showing the problem you have.

Comment: what i meant was, the cards just moved slightly to the left. but they were still stacked  vertically. What I want if for them to move horizontally

Comment: @SqueezyAbby You probably have some `<div>...</div>` improperly nested. Check the HTML source code. Your code is difficult to debug because of its style: Mixing of PHP and HTML, and no attempt to structure with functions or OOP. You missed the `col` class in your columns, but this is not the cause of your problems. It should not be so difficult, see this example: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/PoBWraW

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo '<div class="row">';
    while ($product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
            <form method="post" action="index.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $product['id']; ?>">
                <div class="products">

                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="price" value="<?php echo $product['price']; ?>" />

                    <!-- I think you need rows inside form tag -->
                    
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="<?php echo $product['image']; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $product['name']; ?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <h4>$ <?php echo $product['price'];  ?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-3">
                            <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" class="btn btn-info" value="Add to Cart" />
                        </div>
                    </div> <!-- ./row -->
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
<?php
    } // end while
    echo '</div>';
} // end if

?>
```

Comment: it still stacks and instead just disarrange my product cards

Comment: i think you need rows inside form tag, just i edited previous answer